# How to dump and read json / pickle files into Google Drive through the python API?

Tags: python, json, api, google-drive-api, pickle

I've download the start code from here: http://goo.gl/Tcxkod and followed the instructions and installed the `sample.py` from here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation:

```
alvas@ubi:~/git/UniversalCorpus/drive-cmd-line-sample$ python sample.py
Success! Now add code here.
```

But how do I dump pickle/json files onto the drive and then retrieve it to read from python?

I clicked on the dev documentation and there's no clue other than the **repr** and source code itself: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/python/latest/drive_v2.files.html#get

Comment: I was reading on the subject to help you when I found the [PyDrive project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive) which hides all the complex stuff. If you already know about PyDrive, can I ask you why you don't want to use it? If you have never heard of PyDrive, may I suggest you to use it? :)

Comment: @Nil, this is the first time I heard of PyDrive. Looks great, i'll try to work it out and see how far i can get =)

Comment: Good. Tell me how it goes. If it works for you, I can create a mock answer, it would be m first bounty!

Comment: i'm pretty sure there's a better way to do things with pydrive. I can't seem to dump and read json/pk easily. i've been throwing `collection.Counters` as `str` in txtfiles onto the cloud and then reading them with `ast`. It sort of work but it's a little confusing.

Answer (score 6):

### With PyDrive

I tested [PyDrive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive) and I think it's pretty straigtforward. Here's what I did:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Upload a json file (will be identical for a pickle file)
json_file = drive.CreateFile()
json_file.SetContentFile('wopwop.json')
json_file.Upload() # Files.insert()
print json_file['title'], json_file['id']

# Download the same json file
same_json_file = drive.CreateFile({'id': json_file['id']})
same_json_file.GetContentFile('test.json')  # Save Drive file as a local file
```

There's two "problems" with this code:

- It asks you in a browser if you agree everytime you use it. Read [this page](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html#customizing-authentication-with-settings-yaml) to make him remember your answer.
- As you can see, you need to remember the unique identifier (id) of your file. You could put them in a database or in a local json file. You could also use PyDrive to [list all files matching a query](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filelist.html), thus giving you its id.

### Without PyDrive

If you are not interested in using PyDrive, I strongly suggest you to read its code. If I had to do it, I would place 3 breakpoints (or print) in pydrive.files:

- in `_FilesInsert` on the line `self.auth.service.files().insert(**param).execute()`
- in `_FilesUpdate` on the line `self.auth.service.files().update(**param).execute()`
- in `_DownloadFromUrl` on the line `self.auth.service._http.request(url)` and in the constructor to see how he obtain the url (it's in `self.metadata`)

You already have `service` with the code you downloaded in `sample.py`, so you only need to know what is in the `param` dictionary to understand what's going on.

However, you should use PyDrive ;)