# Can't rename file on server, then upload onto google drive API via service account

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

<s>I have read through several articles/docs/questions now and each solves a part of my problem, but I just can't seem to put them all together to work. I am using Flask/Python, the Google Drive API v3 and a Service Account, but want to run the site on Heroku, which is setup already. Since Heroku doesn't have a storage for files though, I need to directly upload the files into Google Drive, which would need to be done sooner or later anyway.</s>

Basically what I want to do is:

- People type in their data on a website and upload a file.
- That file then gets renamed according to the user's data (needs to support Chinese characters/utf8)
- then the renamed file gets uploaded onto Google Drive using a service account

<s>I was able to rename the file with utf-8 characters and save it locally, but don't know how to upload it to Google.</s>I have tried a way earlier, <s>but I don't know whether just a file has been created with no content or the file has been uploaded properly,</s>I do see files and folders when listing the files/folders (that doesn't work now though, as I think my attempt now is exactly the same).
 My Code:

```
def upload_service(file, filename):

file_metadata = {
        'name': filename,
        'parents': 'Upload'
}

mime = mimetypes.guess_type(file.filename)[0]
media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime)

cloudFile = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media).execute()

result = service.files().list().execute()
```

In here, `file` is the actual file uploaded with the `filename` being the input the user typed in.
All works fine, but for `media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime)` I get a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gtmuCfr.jpg'` error, stating that the file with the name of `filename` or `file` are not there. This goes for the original name of the file and the new name.

Comment: You need to provide the complete path of your file in MediaFileUpload(). If you only provide the filename, it will just try to look for the file in the same directory where your python script is located. You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922944/google-drive-api-uploading-file-python) where file upload was successful.

Comment: @RonM but I am not saving this file at all (and thus I dont have a path), I want to upload it immediately since I don't think that Heroku offers that. It did work without that shortcut earlier if I remember correctly, at least there are several files in my Google Drive Account that have been succesfully uploaded to the service account

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found the issue and was able to fix it (for the most part).

```
with open(new_name.encode("utf-8"), "wb") as save_file:
            file = save_file.write(f.read())
            upload_service(file, new_name)
```

doing it like this solves the issue as `file` is the int where it is stored (I guess), but since it doesn't have a `filename` attribute, I need to use the `path/new_name` inside the function.
The only difference inside the function is:

```
file_metadata = {
        'name': path,
        'parents': 'Upload'
}

mime = mimetypes.guess_type(path)[0]
media = MediaFileUpload(path, mimetype=mime)
```

where I need to use the `path/new_name` that I sent as a second parameter.
Now the only issue left is with the Upload folder/parent not being selected for the upload, but I can see the files (after giving permission) in my Drive and they have the right content.

Comment: You need to specify the folder id as parent in your file metadata. [Create a file in a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#create_a_file_in_a_folder)